# How do I replace all instances of the first letter in a string, but not the first letter itself

Tags: python

My code so far is:

```
def ChangeString():
    print (userString.replace(
userString =str(input("Please enter a string "))
ChangeString()
```

In a string, I need to replace all instances of the first character with a *, without actually replacing the first character itself. An example is, let's say I have "Bobble"; the function would return something like, "Bo**le".

Comment: Yeah, case insensitive

Comment: Wow ! Your code so far .... ?? Really ?

Comment: Dude, I'm learning; I have no idea how to do it, that's why I asked the question

Comment: I get that you are learning, but dont you feel like just seeing if the code compiles once ??

Comment: Bobble was an EXAMPLE; the actual string will be an input

Comment: Someone edited my question; great. That ******* helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userString[0] + userString[1:].replace(userString[0], "*")`

Comment: but this solution is actually case sensitive... :(

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine. Yh, the case sensitivity is sort of a problem, but I'll try figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> test = 'Bobble'    
>>> test = test[0] +''.join(l if l.lower() != test[0].lower() else '*' for l in test[1:])
>>> print test

Bo**le
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a regex:

```
import re

def ign_first(s, repl):
    return re.sub(r"(?<!^){}".format(s[0]), repl, s, flags=re.I)
```

Demo:

```
In [5]: s = "Bobble"

In [6]: ign_first(s, "*")
Out[6]: 'Bo**le'
```

Or use `str.join` with a set:

```
def ign_first(s, repl):
    first_ch = s[0]
    st = {first_ch, first_ch.lower()}
    return first_ch + "".join([repl if ch in st else ch for ch in s[1:]])
```

Demo:

```
In [10]: ign_first(s, "*")
Out[10]: 'Bo**le'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use slices and `lower()`.

```
>>> test = 'Bobble'
>>> test[0] + test[1:].lower().replace(test[0].lower(), '*')
'Bo**le'
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use additional variables

```
>>> st='Bobble'
>>> st=st[0]+st[1:].lower().replace(st[0].lower(),'*')
>>> st
'Bo**le'
```

Answer (score 0):

case-insensitive solution with regular expressions:

```
import re

string = "Bobble"

outcome = string[0]+re.sub(string[0].lower() + '|' + string[0].upper(), 
                           "*", string[1:].lower())

>>>
Bo**le
```

Comment: You will also end up changing all the string to lower, the replacement should be case insensitive but that does not mean every letter is lowercase

Comment: Thank you for the observation Padraic! I edited my answer. It should work now. All occurrences of the first letter are substituted in the word, no matter whether they are upper or lower case, without changing the original string.

Comment: I just saw that you actually posted the same solution shortly before me ^^" haha, sorry for the duplication

Comment: You would need re.I. if you had an uppercase letter in the string like the first lettter of a name, place etc..you would also lower that. The logic needs to do a case insensitive replacement but leave the rest of the string as is.